# removing pointers from linked list in c++

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, hashmap

I wrote this hash map (this was a part of telephonic interview exercise), where I do a `new Node(key, value)` when I put an element. I want to make sure I'm cleaning up when the hashmap itself goes out of scope.

Did I miss anything in here ? Is there any way I can check if there is a memory leak ?

```
class HashMap {
private:
    list<Node*> data[SIZE];

public:
    ~HashMap();
    Node* get(int key);
    void put(int key, int value);

    int hashFn(int val){ return val % 13; }
};

HashMap::~HashMap(){
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i){
        list<Node*>& val = data[i];
        for(list<Node*>::iterator it = val.begin(); it != val.end(); it++){
            Node* n = *it;
            delete n;
        }
    }
}
```

For the curios: complete code is here: http://rextester.com/EHPCYW12862

**EDIT:**

Also, do I *really* need to call list.clear() in the end (since I've already deallocated all the nodes in a list) ?

Comment: looks ok, but's it's better to use smart pointers

Comment: Use boost::ptr_list, and the problem is gone.

Comment: why didnt you use a vector of lists instead?

Comment: it was an interview problem, so could not use externals :)

Comment: @AndersK : I wanted a fixed size array and not something that would grow. (Check out the link I gave for how I implemented it). There can only be `SIZE -1` number of buckets and hence I don't need the array to grow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `put` is constructing a `Node` to put into your hash table, associating the `key` and `value`. There was no need to use a `list<Node *>`, it would have been cleaner to use `list<Node>` instead.

```
list<Node> data[SIZE];
//...
data[bucket].push_front(Node(key, value));
```

Then, you could have avoided implementing a destructor.

Your `get` function can still return a pointer.

```
Node* HashMap::get(int key){
    //...
    list<Node>::iterator it = data[bucket].begin();
    //...
            if (it->key == key) return &*it;
    //...
    return NULL;
}
```

If you leave the implementation with `list<Node *>`, then you should also implement a copy constructor and an assignment operator ([the rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)).

Comment: I initially used a Node. However, when I am trying to `put()` the same value again, I was asked to overwrite the value of that Node. How would I do that using a Node only ?

Comment: Your `get` could return a reference, allowing you to modify the returned `Node`. But cleaner, would probably be a private `get_iter` that returned the iterator so that both `get` and `put` could use it.

Comment: Exactly what I thought :). However, when the node is not found, I can't return NULL through a reference. So something like this would not work: `Node& get(int key)`

Comment: @brainydexter: Did the interviewer define the interface? If not, you can return a `bool`, and accept a reference to a `Node &` to populate. Or, return the address of the of the found `Node` with `&*iter`.

Comment: @user315052 No, I could define the interface. You lost me with your suggestion. Can you write the function definition to clarify ? Thanks

Comment: @user315052 Implemented it with `Node` only here: http://ideone.com/i91fQ. (Sidenote, I wonder why is ideone throwing a runtime error)

Comment: @user315052 I just wanted to confirm: If I were to use list<Node> data[SIZE], I don't have to implement the rule of threes since mighty c++ will take care of it for me ?

Comment: @brainydexter: Yes, because you don't need to implement your own destructor. The rule of 3 is essentially: if you need to implement a destructor for you class, you also need to implement a copy constructor and an assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to check if there is no memory leak is to use smart pointer classes that can not leak. `shared_ptr<Node>` or `unique_ptr<Node>` may do here, the first for the copyable map, the second for noncopyable one.

But in case you have to use raw pointers (homework?), there are things that are missing: copy constructor and assignment operator. Without them either disabled or implemented, copying this HashMap will produce dangling pointers (after one of the maps is destroyed).

Comment: agreed. The rule of threes should be followed here. I was asked to implement a hash map with focus on get()/put() functions

Answer (score 1):

The cleanup is fine. Minor point:

```
   for(list<Node*>::iterator it = val.begin(); it != val.end(); ++it)
```

it is better to use prefixed increment for perf reasons. The postfix form has to give out the state of the iterator before the increment. This object will be immediately discarded. Compiler may optimize, but it depends.

Comment: Ah yes, I learnt that a while back. Thanks for pointing this out. (I did use `++i` in the loop above it :)

Comment: For an int value this does not matter. For iterator that is an object this is more important.

Comment: Dector of `list<>` will clean it up in any case. I would recommend not to call.

Answer (score 1):

Looked throw your code and noticed you are using some overhead constructs.

These two snippets are equivalent

```
Node ** d = &(*it); 
if((*d)->key == key){
    return *d;
}

if((*it)->key == key){
    return (*it);
}
```

Comment: ah yes! At the time of interview, I was panicking and didn't want to pass a copy to a pointer. I realized this later :)